# Elasticsearch Ordering terms aggregation buckets after field in top hits sub aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I would like to order the buckets from a terms aggregation based on a property possessed by the first element in a top hits aggregation.

My best effort query looks like this (with syntax errors):

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "toBeOrdered": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "parent_uuid",
                "size": 1000000,
                "order": {
                    "topAnswer._source.id": "asc"
                }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "topAnswer": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Example:

```
{
  "a":1,
  "b":2,
  "id":4
}
{
  "a":1,
  "b":3,
  "id":1
}
{
  "a":2,
  "b":4,
  "id":3
}
```

Grouping by "a" and ordering the buckets by "id" (desc) and sorting the top hits on "b" (desc) would give:

```
{2:{
  "a":2,
  "b":4,
  "id":3
},1:{
  "a":1,
  "b":3,
  "id":1
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following query. The idea is to show for each `parent_uuid` bucket the first top hit with the minimum `id` value and to sort the `parent_uuid` buckets according the smallest `id` value as well using a `min` sub-aggregation.

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "toBeOrdered": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "parent_uuid",
        "size": 1000000,
        "order": {
          "topSort": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "topAnswer": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "b": "desc"
            }
          }
        },
        "topSort": {
          "max": {
            "field": "id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try it out and report if this works out for you.

Comment: My top_hits however have a different sorting order and I would like to order by the id as sorted by the top_hits.

Comment: What I understood from your question is that you would like `toBeOrdered` to be ordered by the `id` property of the first hit in your `top_hits` sub-aggregation. If not, can you show with some sample documents, how you would like the results to look like?

Comment: Ok, I might have misunderstood your answer, please correct me if I'm wrong. My top_hits however aren't ordered by id, they have a different ordering. Also, updated main post with an example in an attempt to clarify

Comment: Thanks for the examples, they helped. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Either I am missing something or wouldn't this sort on the max id in the bucket rather than the max id returned by the top_hits aggregation?