# Sort aggregations on element of multi-bucket sub-aggregation

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

On Elasticsearch 2.0.0, I'm trying to sort buckets on a multi-bucket `terms` aggregation by the top hit count of a given term.

Here's an example to make things clearer. Say we have the following dataset representing customer purchases:

```
[{
  "id": "95aee6b0-9c41-11e5-8994-feff819cdc9f",
  "name": "Ingrid Bergman",
  "channel": "WEB",
  "productId": 3124,
  "totalPreTax": 221.5
},
{
  "id": "95aee6b0-9c41-11e5-8994-feff819cdc9f",
  "name": "Ingrid Bergman",
  "channel": "MOB",
  "productId": 5527,
  "totalPreTax": 12.5
},
{
  "id": "95aee6b0-9c41-11e5-8994-feff819cdc9f",
  "name": "Ingrid Bergman",
  "channel": "WEB",
  "productId": 1188,
  "totalPreTax": 55.6
},
{
  "id": "2854b9d6-9c42-11e5-8994-feff819cdc9f",
  "name": "Luis Borges",
  "channel": "IPAD",
  "productId": 779,
  "totalPreTax": 119.0
}]
```

What I need is to fetch, for each customer, the average `totalPreTax` and their most frequent `channel`, sort alphabetically by the latter (desc). That is,

```
[{ 
   "id": "95aee6b0-9c41-11e5-8994-feff819cdc9f",
   "name": "Ingrid Bergman",
   "channel": "WEB",
   "totalPreTax": 96.53
 },
 {
  "id": "2854b9d6-9c42-11e5-8994-feff819cdc9f",
  "name": "Luis Borges",
  "channel": "IPAD",
  "totalPreTax": 119.0
}]
```

So far, I have the following (showing only relevant bits), which sorts by the average `totalPreTax`:

```
{ //...
  "aggs": {
    "byCustomer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer.id",
        "order": {
          "averageTotalPreTax": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "averageTotalPreTax": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "totalPreTax"
          }
        },
        "channel": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "channel",
            "order": {
              "_term": "desc"
            },
            "size": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, figuring out the top `channel` for each bucket (aka, each customer) requires a second multi-bucket `term` sub-aggregation. I'm only interested in the first element of that resulting array, which holds the needed value for the most frequent channel. This, prevents me from sorting my `byCustomer` aggregation by using something like:

```
"byCustomer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer.id",
        "order": {
          "channel": "desc"
        }
      }
}
```

Resulting in:

> AggregationExecutionException[Invalid terms aggregation order path [channel]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end

Someone out there, [tackled something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305415) (but not quite my scenario), but didn't properly answered the question.

So, how would I go about doing this? Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Question not tied to ES version. Possible answers can apply to any particular API version.